# How should I go about embedding a collection of new entities in a Symfony2 Form?

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I need to write a form for creating a new entity and with it, up to 3 relations (which are new entities).

I can either have it dynamically attach/delete them dynamically (which could be useful) or have all 3 always be related to the entity, and for them to have an 'active' boolean on them, which would be just as appropriate.

At what point should I be doing this? I need them rendered as checkboxes on the form.

---

So far I've tried attaching them to the entity prior to passing it to the form, but choice fields can't be passed unmapped entities, so that's no good.

I've also tinkered with a DataTransformer for this, although then, as far as I can see, I would have to create new entities in the DataTransformer, which seems wrong, and I can't get to work anyway- I don't have access to the entity within it and even hacking around that, the relationship fails to bind properly (Doctrine tries to save the relationships first).

---

In Symfony1 terms, I could just embed a couple of forms for each additional relation I needed, using new objects, and it'd just work, so surely there's still a relatively easy way around this?

---

A friend also recommended looking into the ResizeFormEventListener, but this, as far as I understand, is for 'resizing' a form based on the returned data, whilst I never want the form to change, I want 3 checkboxes always.

---

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Are you using 2.0 or 2.1?  (Lots of changes in the form system between the two.)  What sort of entity are you making and what are the relations?  It's is not clear to me where the check boxes come in.But I'm guessing that you want to just use a regular choice element and then add the related objects after the form has been validated.  Clarifying the use case might make things clearer.

Comment: I'm using 2.1. Sorry, I wrote this early this morning, what I meant to convey that I also need 3 checkboxes there, regardless of whether or not the objects exist yet (I don't really care) ticking those boxes needs to either set some or all of the objects as 'active' or create them if they don't already exist.

Comment: Ok.  I don't have much hands on experience with 2.1 but you will want to add the three relations, use a "collection" field group and make a form type for the relation which renders the checkbox.  You will then need to ensure that doctrine is happy either by using a cascade or persisting the relations individually before flushing.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the answer, looks like Ben got there first though! I've already got it half working, but thanks regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on exact details without playing with it - but based on how i've done similar things, i'd be looking to use a 'collectiontype' and then adding the three department types into that.